# Typescript: Iterate Through Each Member between Two Classes and Flag Difference in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

How do I compare two class models and find corresponding differences?
Following are two models which have exact same members, and we need to compare.

Is there an algorithm in Typescript which conducts this? * A new result class should be created with class members and  boolean different flag?

Looking for a easy way in Typescript algorithm. It needs to accept any class,

Note: Some members in class contain a class itself.

currently

[image]

**Class:**

```
export class PropertyLocation {   
    streetName: string;
    streetType: string;
    postdirectional?: string;
    unitNumber?: string;
    unitType?: string;
    city: string;
    state?: string;
    postalCode: number;
    postalCodeExtension?: string;

    effectiveStartDate: Date;
    addressChangeReason?: AddressChangeReasonDto
    addressSource?: SourceOfAddressDto;
}
```

**Result Class array sample:**

if there is more optimal storage method, feel free to modify

```
export class DifferenceClass {   
    ClassMember: string;
    DifferentFlag: boolean
}
```

looking for code solution, refraining from third party libraries as company does not prefer

Comment: Can you provide some samples for testing perhaps?

Comment: Not an out of box solution, but this library might be useful to you: https://github.com/flitbit/diff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just build a method/function into your class that runs the comparison. You could do this by comparing each property individually (typing everything out) or just looping every key in your class and comparing it to every key in the passed in object.

```js
class DifferenceClass {   
    constructor(classMember, differenceFlag) {
      this.ClassMember = classMember;
      this.DifferenceFlag = differenceFlag;
    }
}
class Person {
  constructor(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
  isSame(person) {
    if (person instanceof Person) {
      const differences = [];
      for (const key in person) {
        if (this[key] !== person[key]) {
          differences.push(new DifferenceClass(key, true));
        }
      }
      return differences;
    } else {
      throw new Error('Object is not a Person class');
    }
  }
}

const p1 = new Person('John', 'Doe');
const p2 = new Person('Jane', 'Doe');
console.log('Should be empty', p1.isSame(p1));
console.log('Should have diff results', p1.isSame(p2));
console.log('should be an exception', p1.isSame(1));
```

Comment: What about complex properties?

Comment: well, it needs to flag every member that has changed also, not just compare the whole object, see different class sample object at bottom of question

Comment: I would recommend doing it the long way in that case (doing each individual comparison manually). If one of the properties is a complex class, for example, you could make a similar method in that target class.

Answer (score 0):

I have a function that compares two objects and does a deep compare

```
export const compare = (obj1: any, obj2: any): boolean =>
  Array.isArray(obj1)
    ? Array.isArray(obj2) && obj1.length === obj2.length && obj1.every((item, index) => compare(item, obj2[index]))
    : obj1 instanceof Date
    ? obj2 instanceof Date && obj1.getDate() === obj2.getDate()
    : obj1 && typeof obj1 === 'object'
    ? obj2 && typeof obj2 === 'object' &&
      Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj1).length === Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj2).length &&
      Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj1).every(prop => compare(obj1[prop], obj2[prop]))
    : obj1 === obj2;
```

You could use this with

```
const diff = (obj1, obj2) => Object.keys(obj1).map(key => ({ ClassMember: key, DifferentFlag: !compare(obj1[key], obj2[key]) }));
```

Comment: cool, just tried it, do you have detailed answer, it needs to flag every member that has changed also, not just compare the whole object, see different class sample object at bottom of question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [deep-diff](https://github.com/flitbit/diff) library:

```js
import { diff } from 'deep-diff';

const differences = diff(location1, location2);
```

It creates a nice difference object with the paths to the different attributes.

Comment: thanks, it needs to flag every member that has changed also, not just compare the whole object, see different class sample object at bottom of question

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use a pipe to add a class to your template

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

const resolveProperty = (obj: any, property: string): any =>
  property ? property.split('.').reduce((result, prop) => (result ? result[prop] : undefined), obj) : undefined;

@Pipe({
  name: 'different'
})
export class DifferentPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(obj: any, obj2: any, property: string): boolean {
    return resolveProperty(obj, property) !== resolveProperty(obj2, property);
  }
}
```

and in you view you can add a class if the object has changed

```
<div [ngClass]="{ 'changed': original | changed : new : property }">
```

Comment: cool, it needs to flag every member that has changed also, not just compare the whole object, see different class sample object at bottom of question, question title was trying to flag every member

Comment: You put that ngClass statement on each field that needs highlighting and change the property value to the full path to the property, 'streetName.addressChangeReason.prop'

Comment: this is awesome, currently  the old and new property addresses are in different components, the parent component injects the class models into the separate card components,  so a child data cannot see another sibling child data,

Comment: Instead of passing in a diff object pass in the original object